# Have a question about Open Mapping Theorem in functional analysis homework

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let X and Y be Banach spaces. Prove that T ∈ B(X, Y ) is surjective if and only if range(T) is not a meager subset of Y.

I have no clue..hope somebody help me.. thanks!

Comment: It is an "if and only if". Can you at least get one direction?

Comment: I am sorry... I don't remember those concepts and after reviewing I still cannot figure out their relations...

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be the kernel of $T$. Define $S:X|M \to T(X)$ by $S(x+M)=T(x)$. Then $S$ is a bounded linear map. The argument used in Open Mapping Theorem shows that this map is also open. [ In the statement of Open Mapping Theorem it is assumed that the range is complete, but the proof uses only that fact that the range is not meager]. This makes $S$ an isomorphism. As a consequence $T(X)$ is closed. Since $T(X)$ is not meager it must coincide with $Y$. [Because any proper closed subspace of a normed linear space is nowhere dense].

The other direction is trivial. A Banach space is not meager in itself.